# Inject DAO dependency into another DAO class, is this a good practice?

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, dependencies, code-injection

I am writing a web application (news publishing) using Spring MVC. I am now in a situation that I think necessary to inject a DAO dependency in another DAO class. My situation is this:

When retrieving the list of articles from the database, I would like to show the article's author name and the category name it belongs to. However, the schema of my database design is the Article entity only contains the id's of its author and category. For example, the following list of 2 articles:

```
**Article ID    Title           Author    Category**
1            Test Title 1      2          4
2            Test Title 2      3          4
```

To generate this list, I have a method called "getAllArticles()" in ArticleDAO class. In addition, I have two @Transient properties to the Article entity , which are authorName and categoryName. I am thinking about retrieving the authorName and categoryName inside "getAllArticles()" by injecting the dependencies of CategoryDAO and AuthorDAO. So I can basically do the following:

```
for (Article article : articles)
{
    article.setAuthorName(authorDao.getAuthorNameById(article.getAuthorId()));
    article.setCategoryName(categoryDao.getCategoryNameById(article.getCategoryId()));
}
```

Then in my template, I can simply loop through articles and print out the article's author name and category name.

Before I make changes to my DAO classes, however, I would like to confirm if this is a good practice to inject DAO dependency into another DAO class.  Thanks for reply.

Comment: And why would you need another dao for that? Why not simply modify your query to join the other table to access the needed data? IF not you probably run into 1+N (1 query to get articles for each article get the author) select problem.

Comment: thanks M. Deinum. As you can tell, I'm lacking in SQL :)